# angular router is always redirecting me to /#/

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

i have this problem i searched for it in stackoverflow with no result, whene the applications starts the link become 127.0.0.1:4200/#/ after it was 127.0.0.1:4200.

i thought that the probleme is in my environment so i upload it to heroku, but it still the same problem.

my routes are in a normal case:

```
    const AppRoutes:Routes=[
      {path:'',component:IndexPageComponent},
      {path:'Login',component:LoginRegisterComponent},
      {path:'Services',component:ServicesComponent},
      {path:'ContactUs',component:ContactComponent},
      {path:'AboutUs',component:AboutUsComponent},
    ]
```

Comment: https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy

Answer (score 0):

in Angular there is two ways (or strategies as the Angular called them) to resolve a link,

there is **PathLocationStrategy** and **HashLocationStrategy** for more details read [here](https://angular.io/api/common/LocationStrategy)

to enable one you just need to import it first from @angular/common and tell angular to use it in providers that way

```
providers: [
    {provide: LocationStrategy,useClass:PathLocationStrategy}]
```

Comment: in the root routermodule config you should be able fine `useHash` field, if you remove it everyting should work as expected, without what you provided, it  comes by default